# Are there any perfect numbers which are also powerful?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, open-problem

Powerful numbers are discussed in this [paper](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/1986/812820/abs/) by R. A. Mollin and P. G. Walsh.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number) has more information.

In particular, note that [OEIS A001694](http://oeis.org/A001694) does not seem to contain any (even) perfect numbers.

This is indeed the case, if we note that the Mersenne prime $2^p - 1$ has exponent $1$.  (Recall that the general form for even perfect numbers is $N = {2^{p - 1}}(2^p - 1)$.)

Now my question is:  How about odd perfect numbers?

I guess my main inquiry boils down to - Has anyone worked on considering properties of the set $O \bigcap P,$ where $O$ and $P$ are given as follows

$$O = \{\text{odd perfect numbers}\}$$
$$P = \{\text{powerful numbers}\}$$

Any pointers to existing references in the literature will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) that any odd perfect number is of the form $p^rn^2$ where $p$ is a prime, $p$ doesn't divide $n$, and $r\equiv1\pmod4$. The case $r=1$ has not been ruled out, so it has not been proved that every odd perfect is powerful; the cases $r\gt1$ have not been ruled out, so it has not been proved that no odd perfect number is powerful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Gerry Myerson.